# Iterate over Collected list in Java 8 GroupingBy

Tags: java-8

I have a List of Objects say `List<Type1>` that I have grouped using `type`.(using groupingBy)
Now I want to convert that Map> into Type2 that has both the list and the Id of that group.

```
class Type1{
int id;
int type;
String name;
}

class Type2{
int type;
List<Type1> type1List;
}
```

This is what I have written to achieve this:

```
myCustomList
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Type1::getType))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(type1Item -> new Type2() {
                {
                    setType(type1Item.getKey());
                    setType1List(type1Item.getValue());
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works perfectly. But I am trying to make the code even cleaner. Is there a way to avoid streaming this thing all over again and use some kind of flatmap to achieve this.

Comment: If you want to make the code even cleaner, stop creating a subclass of `Type2` (also known as the double-curly-brace anti-pattern). Give `Type2` a constructor accepting the type and type1list. Then, you can simply use `.map(t1 -> new Type2(t1.getKey(), t1.getValue()))`.

Comment: As @Holger commented, I think you don't need to `Type2` class and you can achieve to goal so simple. `Map<Integer,List<Type1>> result = type1List.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Type1::getType));`

Comment: @HadiJ my comment was more about the double-curly-brace initialization pattern, which creates a *subclass* of `Type2`. But yes, if `Type2` is only about these two properties, the `Map<Integer,List<Type1>>` might already be sufficient for most purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `Type2` a constructor of the form

```
Type2(int type, List<Type1> type1List) {
    this.type = type;
    this.type1List = type1List;
}
```

Then, you can write `.map(type1Item -> new Type2(type1Item.getKey(), type1Item.getValue()))` instead of

```
.map(type1Item -> new Type2() {
    {
        setType(type1Item.getKey());
        setType1List(type1Item.getValue());
    }
})
```

<sup>See also [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/2711488)

In short, this creates a memory leak, as it creates a subclass of `Type2` which captures the `type1Item` its entire lifetime.</sup>

But you can perform the conversion as part of the downstream collector of the `groupingBy`. This implies that you have to make the `toList` explicit, to combine it via `collectingAndThen` with the subsequent mapping:

```
Collection<Type2> collect = myCustomList
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Type1::getType,
        collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> new Type2(l.get(0).getType(), l))))
    .values();
```

If you really need a `List`, you can use

```
List<Type2> collect = myCustomList
    .stream()
    .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Type1::getType,
            collectingAndThen(toList(), l -> new Type2(l.get(0).getType(), l))),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a finisher function to the `collectingAndThen` to get the work done after the formation of the initial `map`.

```
List<Type2> result = myCustomList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Type1::getType),
        m -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Type2(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as mentioned below:

```
type1.map( type1Item -> new Type2(
     type1Item.getKey(), type1Item
)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```